# License for your TreeFrog application

Tags: licensing

I have come across the [TreeFrog](http://www.treefrogframework.org) framework.  While its [license](http://www.treefrogframework.org/en/user-guide/introduction/license.html) is BSD, it still uses `qmake` to compile as seen in the [tutorial](http://www.treefrogframework.org/en/user-guide/tutorial/).  So does TreeFrog's BSD license or Qt's LGPL license apply to the application you create using this framework?

Comment: I haven't looked closely enough to give an answer, but it looks like TreeFrog is simply a framework that sits "on top of" Qt. You must comply with Qt's terms separately (whether you opt for a FLOSS license or [buy a different license](https://www1.qt.io/buy-product/)), and TreeFrog's permissive BSD terms will not interfere with whichever Qt license terms you choose to acquire.

Comment: Thank you so much!  `treefrog` is now outta the window.  I could use straight Qt5 if Qt license applies.